# Copying Postgres Data With Nodejs (issue with key word Infinity)

Tags: node.js, pg

So I'm creating an app to go through one table to collect and change some data, then move the updated information to the new table.  The issue I'm running into is the types of columns.  I ran into copying a timestamp that has Infinity instead of timestamp.  When I try to enter the data in the file, I get the following message:

column "infinity" does not exist

Any ideas on what I should be using here?

Query: `insert into schema.table (id,time,processed,in,out) values ('828h29s2838','Tue, 01 Feb 2020 08:58:22 GMT',false,'Tue, 01 Feb 2020 08:58:22 GMT',infinity);`

data in table:
828h29s2838 | 2020-02-01 00:58:22.418 | false | 2020-02-0 00:58:22.455 | infinity

Comment: 1. "I ran into copying a timestamp that has Infinity instead of timestamp" --> please show in table.
2. Show your query

Comment: @yogski I added the information to the original post.  Please let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, I got it now.  I should have placed apostrophes around infinity in my query.

corrected query: insert into schema.table (id,time,processed,in,out) values ('828h29s2838','Tue, 01 Feb 2020 08:58:22 GMT',false,'Tue, 01 Feb 2020 08:58:22 GMT','infinity');